# make-counter which retain the state of variable next

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

I read such a `make-counter` example from [Section 2.9. Assignment of Scheme Programming](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#./start:h9)

```
> (define make-counter
    (lambda ()
      (let ([next 0])
        (lambda ()
          (let ([v next])
            (set! next (+ next 1))
            v)))))
> (define count1 (make-counter))
> (count1)
0
> (count1)
1
```

I am very confused here, how is the state of 'next' maintained?

with my understanding,
`(define count1 (make-counter))`, return the value `v`,then the procedure of `make-counter` gone and destroyed,

When `count1` was invoked again, a fresh `make-counter` called, so the expected results should be "0" constantly.

However, it magically print the following:

```
> (count1)
1
> (count1)
2
> (count1)
3
> (count1)
4
> (count1)
5
```

How the state of 'next' is kept?

Answer (score 1):

It is the [concept of closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), which is a pair of a pointer to environment and a pointer to code.  The variable from the code points to the closure's environment.  Each time when you call the yielder the code will access the closure's environment and update it.

You can do it simpler so:

```
(define make-counter
  (lambda(k)    ;; closure encloses the global env. containing `+`, `-`, `set!`, etc.
    (lambda()   ;; internal closure encloses an environment containing k
      (set! k (+ 1 k))  ;; each call of (counter) mutates `k`
      (- k 1))))
(define counter (make-counter 0))
(counter)
0
(counter)
1
(counter)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

> When `count1` was invoked again, a fresh `make-counter` called, so the expected results should be "0" constantly.

No, `make-counter` is not called again. It is the innermost lambda that is called again, because `(make-counter)` returned the innermost lambda.

To see this more clearly, rewrite `make-counter` like this:

```
(define (make-counter)
  (let ([next 0])
    (lambda ()  ; <- This lambda is the return value of `(make-counter)`.
      (let ([v next])
        (set! next (+ next 1))
        v))))
```

To see it even more clearly, get rid of `make-counter`:

```
> (define count1 (let ([next 0])
                   (lambda ()
                     (let ([v next])
                       (set! next (+ next 1))
                       v))))
> (count1)
0
> (count1)
1
```

Every time you execute `(count1)`, you are executing the body of the lambda.

Even if you call `(count1)` over and over again, `next` will not become `0`, because `(count1)` will only execute the body of the lambda. `next` was only set to `0` when `count1` was initially defined.